# Why I couldn't get clicking element attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Actually it's so simple function but I don't understand why my function is not working ? I want to get current link class or attribute...but it gave me a 'undefined' result.and another issue it's I want to get id,class or another attribute only when I click to link but if I click another place on my document than it behavior as if I click link link

```js
$(function() {

  var tabMenuLink = $(".nav-tabs li a"),
    tabId = tabMenuLink.attr("class");
  $(document).on("click", tabMenuLink, function() {
    alert(tabId);
  });
});
```

```css
ul {
  width: 700px;
  margin: 100px auto;
}

ul li {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css'>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#otel-ara" aria-controls="otel-ara" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" class="otel-ara-tab">OTEL</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#tur-ara" aria-controls="tur-ara" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" class="tur-ara-tab">TUR</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#ucak-ara" aria-controls="ucak-ara" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" class="ucak-ara-tab">UÇAK</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#gemi-ara" aria-controls="gemi-ara" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" class="gemi-ara-tab">GEMİ</a></li>

</ul>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your js code is not right. 
Add click event to li a and get class of clicked element.
try this:

```
$(function() {

  var tabMenuLink = $(".nav-tabs li a");

  tabMenuLink.on("click", function() {
    tabId = $(this).attr("class");
    alert(tabId);
  });
});
```

Comment: absolutely right! how I forgot I don't know but thank you so much

Comment: Ah nice. You did the right clickevent. I just copied his code and add  the line to get the class.

Answer (score 3):

This will work. I'm not sure if you lose scope how you did it.

```js
$(function() {

  var tabMenuLink = $(".nav-tabs li a"),
    tabId = tabMenuLink.attr("class");
  $(document).on("click", tabMenuLink, function() {
    var tabId = $(this).attr('class');
    alert(tabId);
  });
});
```

```css
ul {
  width: 700px;
  margin: 100px auto;
}

ul li {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css'>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#otel-ara" aria-controls="otel-ara" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" class="otel-ara-tab">OTEL</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#tur-ara" aria-controls="tur-ara" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" class="tur-ara-tab">TUR</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#ucak-ara" aria-controls="ucak-ara" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" class="ucak-ara-tab">UÇAK</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#gemi-ara" aria-controls="gemi-ara" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" class="gemi-ara-tab">GEMİ</a></li>

</ul>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
```

Comment: i get undefined alert.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(function() {
  $('.nav-tabs li a').on("click", function() {
    alert($(this).attr('class'));
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
  });
});
```

Add attribute id in your li tag And change your Jquery Code

Comment: try this better An Refecotor Code compare to other answer

Answer (score 0):

You can also use like this

```
$(function() {
   $(document).on("click",'.nav-tabs li a', function() {
      tabId = $(this).attr("class");
      alert(tabId);
   });
})
```